# File claims it contains 0 faces and 0 vertices but in scene view all object names show

Tags: objects, blend-files, scene

I saved my blender file. When I opened that file the next day it appeared empty;  0 faces 0 vertices. But I see all scene names in the scene tab. Also my file size shows.

Why can't I see my objects?

Comment: Seems to be a bug of some sort. If you can repeat it, you should report it to the bug tracker. Is this (the bug, not reporting it) an actual problem to you?

Comment: Have you switched to a different layer? (press `\`` to show all layers) Or perhaps have you entered local view (numpad `/`)?

Comment: If you delete all vertices in edit mode, then move back to object mode, the object still exists, just without any vertices, faces or edges. is that what happened?

Comment: @sarfaraaz if you don't return to answer these questions we can't really ever know if we helped at all. Reason to put on hold at least i think.

Answer (score 2):

#### Viewing a layer which has no objects

maybe you accidentally switched the visible layer to a layer which contains no objects.

[image]

For example if you have all your objects on the first layer (called layer 0), but are viewing the second layer, you won't see anything. Verts/Faces/Tris will say 0, even if the Objects are in the scene.

Pressing the numeric keys <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>... will switch current layer, it is possible that you accidentally pressed one of those.

Comment: well , uploading my model to sketchfab today resulted in: 0 faces and 0 Vertices = no model. The model seemed to be uploading (progress bar showing upload), I opened it again in blender and it have all his faces and vertices. (I have only 1 layer)

Comment: @CatiLaporte You might contact sketchfab about that , they have a support forum. https://forum.sketchfab.com/c/support